# How to create dynamic dropdown based on user multi value of another dropdown in python dash?

Tags: python, drop-down-menu, plotly-dash

I am trying to create dynamic dropdown which should appear and disappear based on my selection

Example: if I choose city a dropdown should appear for city ,when I deselect city the dropdown
for city should disappear

And I am able to create dropdown dynamically but if try to deselect it just create a new dropdown instead of disappear. Any help would be helpful. Thank you

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State, MATCH, ALL

app = dash.Dash(__name__, suppress_callback_exceptions=True)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div('My first dropdown'),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id="dropdown1",
        options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in ['city', 'country', 'continent']],
        value=["city"],
        multi=True,
    ),
    html.Div(id='dynamic-dropdown-container', children=[]),
])

@app.callback(
    Output('dynamic-dropdown-container', 'children'),
    Input('dropdown1', 'value'),
    State('dynamic-dropdown-container', 'children'))
def display_dropdowns(value, children):
    lengthofval=len(value)
    new_element = html.Div([
        html.Div(
            id="title"
        ),
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id={
                'type': 'dynamic-dropdown',
                'index': lengthofval
            },
            options=[]
        ),

    ])
    children.append(new_element)
    return children


@app.callback(
    Output("title","children"),
    Input("dropdown1","value")
)
def display_output(value):
    return html.Div('selected option {}'.format( value[-1]))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a solution to your question, how to dynamically display and hide a dropdown based on another dropdown. The code requires you to output a style value from the callback function that either displays or hides the target html Div element. This can be done with many different values to unhide html Div elements from the same source dropdown (in your code, dropdown1 is a source dropdown).

I've included the full working code, I think if you review it you'll understand how it all connects together.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

app = dash.Dash(__name__, suppress_callback_exceptions=True)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div('My first dropdown'),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id="dropdown1",
        options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in ['city', 'country', 'continent']],
        value="",
        multi=False,
    ),
    html.Div(
        [
            html.Div([
                dcc.Dropdown(
                    id='dynamic-dropdown-container1',
                    options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in ['NYC', 'SFO', 'DFW']],
                    value='',
            )],
            style={
                'display':'block'
                }   
            ),
            html.Div([
                dcc.Dropdown(
                    id='dynamic-dropdown-container2',
                    options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in ['USA', 'Italy', 'Japan']],
                    value='',
                )],
                style={
                    'display':'block'
                }    
            )
        ],
    ),
])

@app.callback(
    Output(
        component_id='dynamic-dropdown-container1',
        component_property='style'
    ),
    [Input(
        component_id='dropdown1',
        component_property='value'
    )]
)
def update_requested_city(map_option):
    if map_option == 'city':
        return {'display': 'block'}
    else:
        return {'display': 'none'}

@app.callback(
    Output(
        component_id='dynamic-dropdown-container2',
        component_property='style'
    ),
    [Input(
        component_id='dropdown1',
        component_property='value'
    )]
)
def update_requested_country(map_option):
    if map_option == 'country':
        return {'display': 'block'}
    else:
        return {'display': 'none'}


@app.callback(
    Output("title","children"),
    Input("dropdown1","value")
)
def display_output(value):
    return html.Div('selected option {}'.format( value[-1]))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: Thank you. But this not what I am looking for. when multi=True multiple value will be selected from the source dropdown 1 accordingly new dropdown will be created. In that selected multi  values if I deselect any that  respective dropdown should disappear .instead it creates new